# AngularJs: What should I use to create my class library (service/factory/provider)?

Tags: angularjs

**I have my main service:**

```
(function (angular) {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .service("mainService", mainService);

mainService.$inject = ["classLibrary"];

function mainService(classLibrary) {
    this.person = new classLibrary.Person("Name", "Surname");
};

})(window.angular);
```

**And next so-called class library:**

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .service("classLibrary", classLibrary); // service/factory/provider ?

    function classLibrary() {

        // Classes:
        this.Person = function(name, surname) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        };
    };

})(window.angular);
```

The question is: what angular component should I use for my class library. I thought about service or factory, but not sure enough what is better in my case.

Comment: read this https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099

Comment: Agreed with @ManiKiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments and answers to this topic I got next solution

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .factory("classLibrary", classLibrary);

    function classLibrary() {

        var factory = {
            getPerson: function(name, surmane) { return new Person(name, surname); },
            getManager: function(name, surmane) { return new Manager(name, surname); }
        };

        // Private members

        function Person(name, surname) {

            this.name = name;
            this.surmane = surname;

            this.toString = function() {
                return this.name + this.surname;
            };
        } 

        function Manager(name, surname) { 

            this.constructor.prototype = Person;
            this.manager = true;
        }

        // ---

        return factory;
    };
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is factory and use the below code to add a factory

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .factory("classLibrary", classLibrary); 

        var classLibrary function() {

        // Classes
       var obj = {
                 fieldname1: "val1",
                 fieldname2: "value2"
       };
      //if your using array of objects use this
       var objArray =[];
    return 
        {
        obj :obj ,
        objArray:objArray
        }
   });
})();
```

A factory can contain all the classess and the related properties. 
If you want to use functions inside a class. You need to create a separate factory that can use these classes and their properties through your controller.

Factory containing methods will be like this.

```
module.factory('ServicecontainingMethods', function(){
    return{

        methodName1:function(){

        },
        methodName2:function(params){

        },

    }
});
```